# Muting a HTML5 audio element using a custom button

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

What's the best way to mute a HTML5 audio element? I don't want the browser's custom controls, so I've been looking at the javascript instead. Unfortunately it just doesn't seem to work for me :( I'm undoubtedly doing something very wrong.

```
    <audio id="background_audio" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="static/audio/clip.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
      <source src="static/audio/clip.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio> 

<a href="#" onclick="document._video.muted=true; return false">mute sound</a>
```

Still getting my head around this. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mute an html5 video player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mute an html5 video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other question is about jQuery. This is about JS.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This [should work](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-media-muted):

```
document.getElementById('background_audio').muted = true;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sVwXH/ (no jQuery)

Comment: You can also add muted="true" to your audio element in plain js, and muted={true} for React :) Tho this isn't for a custom button - it will be helpful to someone.