# Custom html5 audio player

Tags: javascript, html

I found out that there is a new HTML5  tag. I want a HTML/Javascript code but I dont want any jQuery in it. Its for a html doc which will have music playing automaticaly in the background, i would like the code to make a little mute button in the topleft corner of the screen. Heres the standard code to work on.

```
<audio controls="?"* loop="loop">
  <source src="horse.wav" type="audio/wave">
</audio>
```

*: Not sure if to be included

The button may be text or picture and it may change (e.g: mute/unmute or mute then when clicked changes to unmute and back).

Comment: may be dupliacte questions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442427/muting-a-html5-audio-element-using-a-custom-button

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [should work](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-media-muted):

```
document.getElementById('background_audio').muted = true;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sVwXH/ (no jQuery)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442427/muting-a-html5-audio-element-using-a-custom-button)

Comment: Thanks I see you got it from the other question.