# html5 video mute

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mute an html5 video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player)

What is the proper way to create an HTML5 video mute button nowadays?  I've tried the other answer on this site, but it doesn't work.

Here's my HTML for the link:

```
<a href="#" class="muted">Mute</a>
```

My video:

```
<video id="video" controls poster="video.jpg" width="600" height="120" >
<source src="images/recvid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="images/recvid.webm" type="video/webM" />
<source src="images/recvid.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
</video>
```

and my jQuery:

```
 $('.muted').click(function() {
   $('#video').prop('muted', true);
     });
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Have you tried `$('#video').muted=true;` or `$('video')[0].muted=true;`?

Comment: Tried both of those, too.  It's just not muting the way it supposedly should be.

Comment: No errors? Can you duplicate the issue with a jsFiddle?

Comment: Ok, this works in jsFiddle, but it isn't working locally or on my server.  http://jsfiddle.net/ndecesare/Vh6Ts/

Comment: Have you definitely checked the console for errors? f12 on chrome will bring it up. My guess is you're not loading jQuery.