# Adding mute button for video

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I'm looking to create a mute button for a video on my page. My page has a background video with a loop and nothing else. But the sound is just very annoying after a while. I found a button to stop the video, but I can't play it again after. Also, I'm looking for a mute only button.

So that's my HTML currently.

```
<video autoplay id="bgvid" loop>
<source src="videos/chat/chat_noir.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="mute" onclick="document.getElementById('bgvid').pause()">
<a href="#">Activer/Désaciver le son</a>
</div>
```

I have the .pause function, but how to make the video continue and only remove the sound? How to replay video or put the sound again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to introduce the usage of `muted` attribute of `video` html tag as follows:

```
<div class="mute" onclick="document.getElementById('bgvid').muted = !document.getElementById('bgvid').muted">
  <a href="#">Mute / Avtivate</a>
</div>
```

See working **[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/z7r8uonr/)**.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make video play again after stop? (outside of the video controls)

Comment: Nevermind, I found `function playpause(){

    if (bgvid.paused){
        bgvid.play();
    }else{
        bgvid.pause();
    }
}`

Just weird that it doesn't work with if video play() to pause... Just work with paused().

Answer (score 0):

You could add **controls** attribute to video tag.

```
<video autoplay id="bgvid" loop controls>
```

So you will be able to pause and mute video.
Or refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player) if you really want to have your own button for mute.